# Django filtering on related models attributes

Tags: python, django

```
class Count(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name = 'accesses', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    count = models.ForeignKey(Count, related_name = 'accesses', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

With this model scheme, how can i filter on a Count queryset based on the user?

For example, i want every count object that has the first Access Record with a certain user id.

```
user_id = 2
all_counts = Count.objects.all()
list(filter(lambda x: x.accesses.first().user.pk == user_id, all_counts))
```

^^ This would work. However i get a list instead of a query set (i still need to order_by, etc..)

What's the best alternative here?

Edit. Every Count is guaranteed to have at least one Access Record.

Comment: Can you explain why *"first" Access Record*?

Comment: It's related to my use case. I need to find every count that has the first Access Record with that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `accesses` as within a filter.

Thus `Count.objects.filter(accesses__user_id=2)`

But this will retrieve all Count's for this use, not just the ones for each first AccessRecord.

Thus by adding an order by you can do something like

```
first_acccess_count = Count.objects.filter(accesses__user_id=2).order_by('start_time').first()
```

Note: `first_acccess_count` can be None, if user had no access yet.

Edit: Question was unclear, query should do:  I want every count object of that user_id. But the user needs to have the first Access Record.

```
from django.db.models import Max
# First retrieve all first created AccessRecord's, by grouping on 
# Count and to find all lowest ids of AccessRecords. As lower id 
# can be seen as created first.
all_first_records_qs = AccessRecord.objects.values_list('count_id') \
    .annotate(max_id=Min('id')).values_list('max_id', flat=True)
# values_list returns a QuerySet, and thus lazy, which allows it to 
# be used as a subquery
all_counts = Count.objects.filter(
    accesses__user_id=2,
    accesses__id__in=all_first_records_qs,
)
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that every Count is guaranteed to have at least one Access Record.

Also, i don't think that your solution works. You're searching for the first Count object.

I want every count object of that user_id. But the user needs to have the first Access Record.

Comment: For example. A Count object that has two Access Records (1st - user_id = 3, 2nd - user_id = 2) will still pass in your logic, when in reality the count wasn't "created" by the user 2.

Comment: But how can you tell through your current models by who the Count was created? There is no `created_at` or something on AccessRecord, although you could order access per id. Let's see if I can update the answer with a better query.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think I got it right this time.

Comment: I'm sorry if i was unclear. That is exactly what i was looking for. Clever way of using annotate. Thank you